# Return axios response from async service (Vue + Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to return data from axios response from service, but I will always receive from service `undefined`, but inside service I have data. Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

this is how my service looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  async fetchById (articleId) {
    await axios.post('/api/article', { id: articleId })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('axios', response) // valid response
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.error('error', e);
      });
  }
}
```

And there is my usage in component:

```
async created () {
  const article = await articleService.fetchById('12345')
  console.log('article', article) // there I have undefined
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a return statement

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  async fetchById (articleId) {
    // Missing `return` in the next line
    return await axios.post('/api/article', { id: articleId })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('axios', response) // valid response
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.error('error', e);
      });
  }
}
```

I'd encourage you to start using TypeScript, these kind of errors can be easily avoided by having proper typings for functions.

Comment: Good, i'm agree with you typescript  saves the time spent in debugging

Comment: thank you, I didnt aware that inner return not returns value from function

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you could use only `async/await` then return the result :

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {

  async fetchById (articleId) {
     try{
     const  response= await axios.post('/api/article', { id: articleId })
        return response.data
      }catch(e){
        console.error('error', e);
        return null;
      };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use callback() function. this is when you pass a function as a parameter into your existing function which will be executed once your axios call has finished. Here is how it would work with your code:

```js
async fetchById (articleId) {
  await axios.post('/api/article', { id: articleId })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('axios', response) // valid response
    callback(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.error('error', e);
  });
}
```